# ImportError dependency install resulting in NameError

Tags: python, importerror, nameerror

Ive been writing a little script to bootstrap an environment for me, but ran into some confusion when attempting to handle module import errors.  My intention was to catch any import error for the yaml module, and then use apt to install the module, and re-import it...

```
def install_yaml():
    print "Attempting to install python-yaml"
    print "=============== Begining of Apt Output ==============="
    if subprocess.call(["apt-get", "-y", "install", "python-yaml"]) != 0 :
        print "Failure whilst installing python-yaml"
        sys.exit(1)
    print "================= End of Apt Output =================="
    #if all has gone to plan attempt to import yaml
    import yaml
    reload(yaml)

try:
    import yaml
except ImportError:
    print "Failure whilst importing yaml"
    install_yaml()

grains_config = {}
grains_config['bootstrap version'] = __version__
grains_config['bootstrap time'] = "{0}".format(datetime.datetime.now())

with open("/tmp/doc.yaml", 'w+') as grains_file:
    yaml.dump(grains_config, grains_file, default_flow_style=False)
```

Unfortunately when run I get a NameError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "importtest-fail.py", line 32, in <module>
    yaml.dump(grains_config, grains_file, default_flow_style=False)
NameError: name 'yaml' is not defined
```

After some research I discovered the reload builtin (Reload a previously imported module), which sounded like what I wanted to do, but still results in a NameError on the yaml modules first use.

Does anyone have any suggestions that would allow me to handle the import exception, install the dependencies and "re-import" it?

I could obviously wrap the python script in some bash to do the initial dependency install, but its not a very clean solution.

Thanks

Comment: you have done it in the local scope of a `function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You imported `yaml` as a *local* in `install_yaml()`. You'd have to mark it as a global instead:

```
global yaml
```

inside the function, or better still, move the import *out* of the function and put it right after calling `install_yaml()`.

Personally, I'd *never* auto-install a dependency this way. Just fail and leave it to the administrator to install the dependency properly. They could be using other means (such as a virtualenv) to manage packages, for example.

Comment: Thankyou, that makes a lot of sense, I hadn't ever thought of imports as being in a scope.  But i suppose that because I've always imported them at the beginning of the script.

I can understand your reasoning for not auto installing, but in this case its to bootstrap our configuration management system, which will then manage any future dependencies.